# How to login user with laravel with cakephp database where password is hashed (like string is serialized and then encypted) using sha1

Tags: laravel, cakephp

```
$hashParts = array(
            $this->request->here(),
            serialize($fieldList),
            $unlocked,
            Configure::read('Security.salt')
);
$check = Security::hash(implode('', $hashParts), 'sha1');
```

Comment: you will need to hash the users input and compare the two hashes, if they are equal you can log them in

Comment: You can use the same Password hash in Laravel. But I would advise you to change the password hashing if you use sha1, thats not the safest option.

Comment: we create Hash::make('password) like this in laravel but I am not able to match hash generated in cakephp with laravel hash as cakephp generating 440e3d255d82521bdbbf82ad52f93b499df8af6d but laravel generates FAT6P8kgYH75BrMDe97DRe5tairhJSQ0WLscQ2Og08uqN0HKcrYQG

Comment: That's not how CakePHP hashes passwords, the code snippet that you're showing here is part of [post data validation](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.9.9/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php#L514-L520) in older versions.